# The value returned from Apps Script has a type that cannot be used by the add-ons platform. Also make sure to call 'build' on any builder before retur

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, gmail

I have created an html page in app script with simple anchor tag but it is working for few links and getting error for other links.

this is my html - https://prnt.sc/1znf5cn

app script code - https://prnt.sc/1znfdcn

error Description - The value returned from Apps Script has a type that cannot be used by the add-ons platform. Also make sure to call 'build' on any builder before returning it. Value: 'Object with values: '

though if i change url to google.com html its working.

I don't understand what am doing here.

Comment: Please paste your code directly in the question and use [syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: I will not follow unknown links.  Nor will I follow links to documents in another google account.